# which/how to properly use a loop for html change with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, sharepoint-2013

I am new in Javascript and trying to change the HTML content of a line.

I've been helped a little by a friend who made this code for me, but I'm running into major issues.

The situation is:
I'm creating a FAQ in SharePoint 2013, and this code is supposed to read a list, read 3 informations (Category, Question and Answer) and then substitute the HTML where I want it to.

The issue is that it is running on every '.cd-faq__trigger' that is inside it's "i.category", changing them all to the same "i.question"

```
function ChangeHTML(){
        var items = GetListItems("X", "Y", "Z")

        items.forEach(function(i){ 
            $('#'+i.category+' .cd-faq__trigger').html(i.question)
        });
        }
    }
-----------------HTML ------------------

<div class="cd-faq__items">
    <ul id="Compras_TI" class="cd-faq__group">
        <li class="cd-faq__title"><h2>Compras TI</h2></li>
        <li class="cd-faq__item">
            <a id="trigger" class="cd-faq__trigger" href="#0"><span id="texto"></span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the piece of html, where the .cd-faq__trigger class is positioned.

Comment: I'm think just a simple `if innerText=""`, so it only writes in empty <span> will do, but I can't figure how to do that

Comment: More interesting was what the result/return value of `GetListItems("X", "Y", "Z")` does look like.

Comment: The return is a array length 2 of the 2 items that are on the SharePoint list. From which i take the variables: Category, Question and Answer (all obligatory field when creating a new item on the list). The idea is that the code check in which **Category** the item is, and change the **Question** and **Answer** aconrdingly. I'm now thinking that maybe it should re-write the whole html code, to make it more dinamic and hopefully eaiser to manipulate the way I want to... Any helpers on how to do that? _(laughs nervously)_

Comment: And what is the i.category in the html snippet above? Compras_TI?

Comment: Yes, it is! In this case it is, but there are more cotegories, in different parts of the code it will read the different categories and only chance the Questions and Answers in the part of the HTML of their respective categories.

Comment: (just a 'btw': Engilhsh is not my first language, so I apologize in advance)

Comment: thank you @OnkiHara and Peter for the help! I've decided I'll make the Scritp write the who html line for each item in each category. That should solve it. I'll post it as an answer if I solve it

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out how to do it... Made the script write the whole HTML from scratch and then no need to substitute nothing.

SCRIPT:

```
 function AddCategory(){
        var items = GetListItems("ListID", "caml", "url")
        items.forEach(function(i){ 
            $('#'+i.Categoria).append('<li class="cd-faq__item"><a id="trigger" class="cd-faq__trigger trigger" href="#0"><span>'+i.Pergunta+'</span></a><div class="cd-faq__content"><div class="text-component"><p>'+i.Resposta+'</p></div></div></li>')  
        });
    }
```

'i.Categoria' = each category from the list.
'i.Pergunta' = each question posted on the list.
'i.Resposta' = each answer posted on the list.

HTML:

```
<div class="cd-faq__items">
      <ul id="Compras_TI" class="cd-faq__group">
             <li class="cd-faq__title"><h2>Compras TI</h2></li>       
      </ul> <!-- cd-faq__group -->
</div>
```

So it looks for the Category of the post, and inside of it it appends the HTML adding in it the question and answer posted.

Thank you for who helped!